# How can I completely clear a Memgraph database

Tags: memgraphdb

I've run the query `MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n;` and I can see that there are no nodes and relationships left. The message says that Memgraph is empty, but I can still see 9 Indexes.

`SHOW INDEX INFO;` will display them. Do I need to drop them one by one using `DROP INDEX ON :Label;` and `DROP INDEX ON :Label(property);`?

How do I delete them all at once?

[image: Droped all nodes and relationships]

Comment: There is [a request](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/issues/365) to `drop index on *` but it's not implemented yet.
Obviously, deleting data should not drop any index. I agree there should be a `truncate` or something similar to the relational systems.

Comment: Thank you @FrancoisVanderseypen! The answer then seems to be CALL schema.assert({}, {}, {}, true) 
YIELD action, key, keys, label, unique
RETURN action, key, keys, label, unique;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link that @FrancoisVanderseypen has added to his comment there is a [link to GitHub](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/issues/365) issue where this code is located:

```
CALL schema.assert({}, {}, {}, true) 
YIELD action, key, keys, label, unique
RETURN action, key, keys, label, unique;
```

The solution is to use `schema.assert` function.